# Why isn't onClick working for my button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, onclick

I'm attempting to have the "Guess!" button to run a function from my JavaScript file (creating a hangman game), but it doesn't seem to be doing anything when I click on the button. I've double checked to make sure that I'm guessing a correct letter, but everything still appears to be in underscores. Did I do something wrong when I used onClick in the button of my HTML page?

CODE:

```js
//create array for words
var listWords = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'];

//displays the word in underscores
var hiddenWord = [];

//choose word randomly
//Math.random returns integer between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)
//multiply Math.random with the length of the listWords array
//Math.floor rounds down to nearest integer
//note that array indexes start counting from 0, hence why we need to make sure the listWords index never reaches the actual length of the array
var chosenWord = listWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * listWords.length)];

//number of tries the user gets before game over
var lives = 5;

//connected string of underscores that player sees in place of the chosenWord
var answerString;

//function creating underscores to be displayed in place of chosenWord
function hideWord() {
  //for each letter in the chosenWord, replace it with an underscore in the new array
  for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
    hiddenWord[i] = '_';
  }
  //joins each underscore (element) of the hiddenWord array into a string with a space in between each
  answerString = hiddenWord.join(' ');

  //return the new string with spaces in between the underscores
  return answerString;
}

function compareLetter() {
  //get the letter that the player typed in the text box
  var guess = document.getElementById("guessedLetter").value;

  //checking to see if player typed a letter
  if (guess > 0) {

    //compare the player input letter to the answer by moving through the chosenWord's array
    for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {

      //if the player's letter matches one in the chosenWord, then display it
      if (chosenWord[i] === guess) {
        hiddenWord[i] = guess;
      }
    }
    answerString = hiddenWord.join(' ');
    document.getElementById('hiddenWord').innerHTML = answerString;
  }
}


//main function where actions are performed; where the other functions are called
function main() {
  //creating the underscores to hide the chosenWord from the player
  var underscores = document.getElementById("hiddenWord");
  underscores.innerHTML = hideWord();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--title to appear on the tab of the browser-->
  <title>Midterm: Hangman</title>

  <!--linking a CSS style sheet for the page-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="hangman.css">


  <!--running the hangman game-->
  <script src="hangman.js"></script>
</head>

<!--run the main function from the javascript file when page is loaded-->

<body onLoad="javascript:main()">
  <!--adding a title that will appear on the webpage-->
  <h1>Hangman</h1>

  <!--create a text box, restrict to only one letter being able to be typed, create placeholder text-->
  <input id="guessedLetter" type="text" maxlength="1" minlength="1" placeholder="Guess a letter" />

  <!--create a button to submit guessed letter and run the compareLetter function when clicked-->
  <button type="button" onClick="javascript:compareLetter()">Guess!</button>

  <!--underscores to hide the word that the player is guessing-->
  <div id="hiddenWord"></div>

  <!--add instructions for the player-->
  <h2>Instructions</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to put `javascript:` in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed in attributes that contain URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onClick works fine, you must check the length of the `guess` variable like this:

```
if (guess.length > 0) {
   // ...
}
```

The way you do it currently, you are comparing a (possibly empty) string to a number (0), the results may not be what you think, see [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in JavaScript.

Note : The value of an input is always retrieved as a string, even if it contains only digits.

```js
//create array for words
var listWords = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'];

//displays the word in underscores
var hiddenWord = [];

//choose word randomly
//Math.random returns integer between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)
//multiply Math.random with the length of the listWords array
//Math.floor rounds down to nearest integer
//note that array indexes start counting from 0, hence why we need to make sure the listWords index never reaches the actual length of the array
var chosenWord = listWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * listWords.length)];

//number of tries the user gets before game over
var lives = 5;

//connected string of underscores that player sees in place of the chosenWord
var answerString;

//function creating underscores to be displayed in place of chosenWord
function hideWord() {
  //for each letter in the chosenWord, replace it with an underscore in the new array
  for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
    hiddenWord[i] = '_';
  }
  //joins each underscore (element) of the hiddenWord array into a string with a space in between each
  answerString = hiddenWord.join(' ');

  //return the new string with spaces in between the underscores
  return answerString;
}

function compareLetter() {
  console.log('click')
  //get the letter that the player typed in the text box
  var guess = document.getElementById("guessedLetter").value;
console.log(guess);
  //checking to see if player typed a letter
  if (guess.length > 0) {
console.log('yes');
    //compare the player input letter to the answer by moving through the chosenWord's array
    for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {

      //if the player's letter matches one in the chosenWord, then display it
      if (chosenWord[i] === guess) {
        hiddenWord[i] = guess;
      }
    }
    answerString = hiddenWord.join(' ');
    document.getElementById('hiddenWord').innerHTML = answerString;
  } else {
  console.log('no');
  }
}


//main function where actions are performed; where the other functions are called
function main() {
  //creating the underscores to hide the chosenWord from the player
  var underscores = document.getElementById("hiddenWord");
  underscores.innerHTML = hideWord();
}
```

```html
<!--run the main function from the javascript file when page is loaded-->

<body onLoad="javascript:main()">
  <!--adding a title that will appear on the webpage-->
  <h1>Hangman</h1>

  <!--create a text box, restrict to only one letter being able to be typed, create placeholder text-->
  <input id="guessedLetter" type="text" maxlength="1" minlength="1" placeholder="Guess a letter" />

  <!--create a button to submit guessed letter and run the compareLetter function when clicked-->
  <button type="button" onClick="compareLetter()">Guess!</button>

  <!--underscores to hide the word that the player is guessing-->
  <div id="hiddenWord"></div>

  <!--add instructions for the player-->
  <h2>Instructions</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah! I see, thank you so much! So from what I understand, the user input is being read in as a string, which is why just using "guess" didn't work?

Comment: The value of an input is always retrieved as a string, even if it contains only digits.